# R - ggplot boxplot with standard deviation values printed in the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, tibble

I've tried to write this question as clear and complete as possible, and would appreciate your constructive criticisms:

I have a `tibble` named `my_tibble` that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 36 x 5
# Groups:   fruit [4]
   fruit length weight length_sd weight_sd
   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Apple  0.531 0.0730     0.211    0.0292
 2 Apple  0.489 0.0461     0.211    0.0292
 3 Apple  0.503 0.0796     0.211    0.0292
 4 Apple  0.560 0.0733     0.211    0.0292
 5 Apple  0.533 0.0883     0.211    0.0292
 6 Apple  0.612 0.127      0.211    0.0292
 7 Apple  0.784 0.0671     0.211    0.0292
 8 Apple  0.363 0.0623     0.211    0.0292
 9 Apple  1.000 0.0291     0.211    0.0292
10 Apple  0.956 0.0284     0.211    0.0292
# ... with 26 more rows
```

The `length_sd` and `weight_sd` variables are standard deviations of `length` and `width` (yes I know the numbers are nonsensical) for each of the grouped four fruits in the `fruit` factor variable, namely `Apple`, `Banana`, `Orange`, and `Strawberry`.

I want to make a box plot of their lengths and weights, so I `gather()`ed the data first:

```
my_tibble_gathered <- my_tibble %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    gather("length", "weight", key = "measurement", value = "value")
```

Then I ran `ggplot2` to make the box plots with `facet_grid()`:

```
ggplot(data = my_tibble_gathered) +
    geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = fruit, y = value)) + 
    facet_grid(~measurement)
```

Which gives me:

[image: Boxplot of my_tibble]

So far so good.

*However*, I haven't used the standard deviation data yet. What I'd like is to:

1. Print values of the standard deviations (of length or weight *depending on which facet they are in*) for each fruit *inside* the main plot,
2. nudged to not touch the box plots themselves, and
3. at a specified number of decimal places (e.g. 3) with given font and font size.
4. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the standard deviation symbol (sigma) in it, too (so maybe some use of `expression()`?).

So, for example, on top of the box plot for `Apple` `length`, there would be text that reads "[sigma symbol] = 0.211", same goes for the other `fruit`s.

How do I do this programatically and take the data from `my_tibble` so that I don't have to manually copy/paste the numbers via `annotate()`?

Thank you very much.

Here is the `dput()` of `my_tibble`:

```
my_tibble <- structure(list(fruit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Apple", 
"Banana", "Orange", "Strawberry"), class = "factor"), length = c(0.530543135476024, 
0.488977737310336, 0.503193533328075, 0.560337485188931, 0.533439933009971, 
0.611517111445543, 0.784118643975375, 0.362563771715571, 0.999994359802019, 
0.956308812233702, 0.332481969543643, 0.562729609348448, 0.635908731579197, 
0.565161511593215, 0.526448727581439, 0.429069715902935, 0.460919459557728, 
0.444385050459595, 0.503366669668819, 0.618141816193079, 0.516525710744663, 
0.481938965057342, 0.505085048888451, 0.457048653556098, 0.536921608675353, 
0.511397571854412, 0.442487815464855, 0.50103115023886, 0.305442471161553, 
0.424241364519466, 2.45596087585689e-09, 0.122698840602406, 0.131431902209926, 
0.205210819820745, 0.154445620769804, 0.161286627937974), weight = c(0.0729778030869548, 
0.0460942475327506, 0.0796304213241703, 0.0732813711244074, 0.0882995825748408, 
0.127183436952234, 0.0670534170610057, 0.0622813564507915, 0.0290840877242033, 
0.0283807418126428, 0.107361724942771, 0.119133737366527, 0.185844270761176, 
0.108155205104857, 0.189750275168087, 0.0845939609954818, 0.146490609941214, 
0.14150784543994, 0.122840037806175, 0.143552891056291, 0.16798564927051, 
0.241024152676673, 0.237508762873311, 0.20455939607561, 0.316350856257808, 
0.30730862083812, 0.184386251393058, 0.181923008217247, 0.332024894278287, 
0.194530111145869, 0.0166977795512452, 0.0569762924658561, 0.0739793228272142, 
0.0433330479654348, 0.099781312832018, 0.0396375225550451), length_sd = c(0.21053610140121, 
0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 
0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 0.21053610140121, 
0.21053610140121, 0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 
0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 
0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 0.0933430177635132, 0.067296241260161, 
0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 
0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 0.067296241260161, 
0.067296241260161, 0.0695477116271205, 0.0695477116271205, 0.0695477116271205, 
0.0695477116271205, 0.0695477116271205, 0.0695477116271205), 
    weight_sd = c(0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 
    0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 
    0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 0.0292441784658992, 
    0.0292441784658992, 0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 
    0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 
    0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 
    0.033755823218546, 0.033755823218546, 0.0611975080850528, 
    0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 
    0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 
    0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 0.0611975080850528, 
    0.0290125579882519, 0.0290125579882519, 0.0290125579882519, 
    0.0290125579882519, 0.0290125579882519, 0.0290125579882519
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -36L), vars = "fruit", labels = structure(list(
    fruit = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", 
    "Strawberry"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), vars = "fruit", drop = TRUE), indices = list(0:9, 20:29, 
    10:19, 30:35), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 
6L), biggest_group_size = 10L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this a little bit hackish one:

```
d %>% 
  # transform from wide to long similar as you did already
  gather(k, v, -fruit, -ends_with("sd")) %>% 
  # add corresponding sd values 
  mutate(label = ifelse(k == "length", length_sd, weight_sd)) %>% 
  # prepare the label as expression
  mutate(label = paste0("sigma==", round(label, 3))) %>%       
  # add factor for alpha by adding the second group 
  group_by(k, add = T) %>% 
  mutate(Alpha=c(1, rep(0, n()-1))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fruit, v)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text(aes(y=max(v) + 0.1,  
            label=label,
            alpha=factor(Alpha)), 
            size=3,
            show.legend = F, 
            parse = T) +
  facet_grid(~k) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0, 1))
```

[image]

You have to transform the data that the `sd` values correspond to the `fruit` and  `k` column like in the column `label`. Then you have to add a binary factor to avoid overplotting using alpha parameter.

```
d %>% 
  gather(k, v, -fruit, -ends_with("sd")) %>% 
  mutate(label=ifelse(k == "length",length_sd,weight_sd )) %>% 
  group_by(k, add=T) %>% 
  mutate(Alpha=c(1,rep(0,n()-1))) %>% 
  head(3)
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   fruit, k [1]
  fruit length_sd weight_sd k          v label Alpha
  <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Apple     0.211    0.0292 length 0.531 0.211     1
2 Apple     0.211    0.0292 length 0.489 0.211     0
3 Apple     0.211    0.0292 length 0.503 0.211     0
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimbou, the code is a bit complicated for me but I am working through it line-by-line trying to understand it. In the meantime, (1) is there a way to use the actual Greek sigma symbol in the plot instead of spelling out "s-i-g-m-a"? and (2) what does "overplotting using alpha parameter" refer to and what does the `Alpha` variable do???

Comment: @hpy delete `alpha=factor(Alpha)` then you will see that the text is plotted 5-times. So to hide four of them, you either have to decrease the size or the alpha value. Therefor I added one `1` and four `0`'s to each `fruit` and `k` combination. See my edits

Comment: Thank you for your edits, it worked for me! Quick last question: Can you explain your use of the "-" in your `gather()`? I am not familiar with what `-fruit, -ends_with("sd")` means. Is it to specify which variables *to keep* in addition to the ones being gathered? Or does it mean something else? Thanks!

Comment: exactly, see her `?gather()` "... select all variables between x and z with x:z, exclude y with -y."

Comment: I see, thank you. What I don't understand is why use "-" when the goal is to **keep** `fruit` and `ends_with("sd")`? Is the "-" negated by something???

Comment: I included the `-` as I don't want that the `sd`-columns are gathered.

Comment: Oooh I finally get it now. The "-" is to *prevent* certain variables from being `gather()`ed, makes sense now. Thank you!